# Optimize LINQ for IList

Tags: c#, .net, linq, optimization, skip

A while ago I wrote an `IList` extension method to enumerate across part of a list by using the indices. While refactoring I realized a similar query could be performed by calling `Skip(toSkip).Take(amount)`. While benchmarking this I noticed that `Skip` isn't optimized for `IList`. With a bit of googling I ended up at a Jon Skeet post, [discussing why optimizing methods like `Skip` is dangerous](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-40-optimization/).

As far as I understand the article, the problem is no exception is thrown in the optimized methods when the collection is modified, but as a comment states the msdn documentation conflicts itself.

In [IEnumerator.MoveNext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx):

> If changes are made to the collection,
>   such as adding, modifying, or deleting
>   elements, the enumerator is
>   irrecoverably invalidated and the next
>   call to MoveNext or Reset **throws an
>   InvalidOperationException.**

In [IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspxundefined):

> If changes are made to the collection,
>   such as adding, modifying, or deleting
>   elements, the enumerator is
>   irrecoverably invalidated and its
>   behavior **is undefined**.

I see merit in both conventions, and am a bit lost whether or not to optimize. What is a proper solution? I've been considering an `IList.AssumeImmutable()` approach along the lines of `AsParallel()` as mentioned by Kris Vandermotten in the comments. Does any implementation already exist, or is it a bad idea?

Comment: If Jon concludes it would be a mistake to optimize `Skip` etc, and has a paragraph explaining why... then I'd take that as good reasoning.

Comment: I think the "undefined" semantics are more pragmatic than the "throws an exception" semantics (even though the latter is more solid), merely because the latter requires every enumerator instance be able to test for modification of the host container.  Ugh!

Comment: Jon's point still stands, however.  There's nothing to stop you writing an `ItemsInRange(Lo, Hi)` enumerator *without* using `Skip/Take`.

Comment: @Rafe: I wrote an answer to that effect and deleted it because by symmetry `ItemsInRange` should exist for `IEnumerable` as well and that will throw, so the `IList` version cannot be optimized by Jon's argument.

Comment: @Marc: How do we know that Jon was right upon rethinking and not right in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Rafe that the undefined behavior is more correct. Only versioned collections can throw exceptions and not all collections are versioned (arrays being the largest example). Even versioned collections might misbehave if you make exactly 2^32 changes between calls to `MoveNext`.

Assuming you really care about the versioning behavior, the solution is to get an `Enumerator` for the `IList` and call `MoveNext` on it for every iteration:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Skip<T>(this IList<T> source, int count)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
            while (count < source.Count && e.MoveNext())
                yield return source[count++];
    }
```

This way you get O(1) behavior by indexing, but you still get all the exception throwing behavior of calling `MoveNext`. Note that we only call `MoveNext` for the exception side-effects; we ignore the values that it's enumerating over.

Comment: Interesting solution! It looks a bit hackish bit actually really makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) class might help with your immutable collection.

My advice: I personally would not try to "trick" the compiler unless you are having a performance issue. You never know, the next version could make your optimized code run twice as slow as the original. Don't preemptively optimize. The methods provided in the framework can produce some really optimized code that would be difficult to re-implement.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc79sx1.aspx) is an article from msdn that gives info on what collections to use for different purposes. I would use an appropriate collection for the task instead of trying to optimize Skip and Take.

Comment: I don't understand how your answer relates to the question.

Comment: _"The problem is that the next line of code that executes may not be a call to MoveNext()"_ Care to clarify?

Comment: @Steven - did not mean to post that first paragraph. I started to answer thinking you were asking something else. I have updated it to remove that text.

Comment: I seriously need to stop answering questions right before bed.