# Select bottom N from Generic List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic list of integer and it contains random numbers. How would I select the last n elements from the list using LINQ?

I know can use myList.GetRange(index, count) to get the last n elements from the list. Is there a way to do it in LINQ?

THanks

regards,
Balan

Comment: In general, I would not use Linq instead of functionality built into a type because it may be less performant.  Linq works on IEnumerable meaning that the whole list must be traversed. GetRange may be more optimal.

Comment: @Maciej I was under the impression that LINQ was transparently optimised when operating on `ICollection` and `IList`. Depending on the query, it does not necessarily mean that the entire list must be traversed.

Comment: @Bradley: Yes, in some cases it is optimized, but not always. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245172/why-isnt-skip-in-linq-to-objects-optimized

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var count = myList.Count;

myList.Skip(count-n)
```

Update:

*removed redundant Take.*

Answer (score 5):

You could use `myList.Reverse().Take(n)` to achieve what you want.

Comment: You'd need an additional call to `Reverse` - `myList.Reverse().Take(n).Reverse()` - to return the elements in the same order as they are stored in the original list.

Comment: @BACON Good point, though order may not be important if the list contains only random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use skip:

```
myList.Skip(index).ToArray()
```